# jQuery selector for all the cols except the first col on a table

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, css-tables

I want to apply right alignment for all the columns except for the first column.

I wrote the following, but which is working fine. But how can i combine these to statements in to one line.

```
$("table.ftable tr:gt(0)").css("text-align", "right");
$("table.ftable td:first-child").css("text-align", "left");
```

Any Ideas..?

Comment: try using `.shift()` method for remove the first element of array..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using CSS in a style sheet. avoid js to css at all costs if you can!.. an accumulation of these will make your app slower.

http://jsfiddle.net/KCb4K/2/

```
table td {
   text-align:right;
}

table tr td:first-child {
    text-align: left !important;
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$("table td:first").css("text-align", "left");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
table.ftable tr:nth-child(n+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
$(".ftable td:gt(0)").css("text-align", "right");
```

http://jsbin.com/ivegoh/edit

Comment: This is working for only the first row, but if i am having lot rows this wont work right..?